# Convert an enigmatic string using many common decoding algorithms, to check which one works

Tags: reverse-engineering

When reverse-engineering, you often have to make sense out of values like `SGkgVG9tYXMh`. Most often, such values are just encoded with a simple algorithm like Base64/BinHex/Uuencoding/Xxencoding/GEDCOM/Ascii85/6PACK/etc.

My dream would be a program that would take my string and decode it using about a hundred different common decoding algorithm, and output the result. A quick look at the hundred results would quickly tell me what is the right algorithm:

```
SGkgVG9tYXMh →  æ–‡å—åŒ–ã‘
                hÃ⁠¤Ã⁠¤yÃ⁠¶
                µRVÖZTëRŠ TšK™
                Hi Tomas!              ← I find this one visually
                Ã¾jÃ³Ã°lÃ¶Ã°
                я╗┐╪з┘Д╪е╪╣┘
```

Free, preferably usable offline, ideally a JavaScript/HTML page hosted and runnable directly from Github/Gitlab. Any other software form is OK, any OS is OK.

Comment: Does it have to be a web application, or is command-line ok?

Comment: @bariumbitmap: Any is fine!

Comment: Any OS preferences?

Comment: @bariumbitmap: Any OS is OK.

Comment: There is an open-source python project that tries to determine the HASH algorithm used to encode a string https://github.com/psypanda/hashID, however, I never seen anything similar about encryption algorithms. Maybe you will consider to make a bounty because the existance of this software could be very hard to discover.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: My question is NOT about encryption. It is about simple encoding/decoding algorithms like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this idea intriguing, but I couldn't find anything that already existed, so I wrote a Python3 script that does it. Here's an example of its output:

```
$ printf 'SGkgVG9tYXMh' | python3 try_decodings.py
Base64  : Hi Tomas!
Ascii85 : b'\x9c\xfeA\xadw%\xd1\xc8\x8b'
Base85  : b'W\xb9\x92{2"\xbd\x0fF'
ROT13   : FTxtIT9gLKZu
Failed to decode: Base32, Base16, Uuencoding, BinHex
Output same as input: MIME quoted-printable, Percent-encoding, HTML
```

The code is here:

https://github.com/nbeaver/try-decodings

It doesn't check for Unicode encoding issues, but it does try to convert bytes to the default encoding if possible.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems to encode then decode, round-trip? I am looking for a tool that only decodes. I would give my dream tool an **already-encoded string**, and it would show decoded strings.

Comment: It does decode, but runs a round-trip self-test if there are no arguments. Don't forget the `-` afterward. Right now it takes both `stdin` and filenames, although I'm thinking about changing that, since it's somewhat confusing.

Comment: Indeed I had forgotten the `-` it seems thanks :-)

Comment: Good. Feel free to email me or open a Github request if you run into any trouble. The `binhex` output in particular has some issues I haven't fixed yet.

Comment: I've removed the need for the `-` and made the `binhex` use tempfiles now instead.

Comment: Might want to include a test so that if a given encoding spits out unchanged text, it's suppressed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I implemented that also.